# Can't run my C code in netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, makefile

I am trying to run simple **C** program in netbeans:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello");

}
```

=================================================

But I'm getting following error:

```
cd 'C:\Users\bhatt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/bhatt/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/bhatt/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o newfile.c
newfile.c:6:1: fatal error: opening dependency file build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d: Permission denied
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/bhatt/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/bhatt/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 956ms)
Please help urgently
```

Comment: BTW:  there are two valid signatures for the `main()` function: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   I.E. the return type is always `int` so, if the `gcc` utility had gotten that far, it would have output a message about the return type from `main()`

Answer (score 0):

here is the main problem:

```
newfile.c:6:1: fatal error: opening dependency file build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d: Permission denied
```

which means the `gcc` utility did not have permission to create a new file in the directory: `build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/`

Comment: how do I rectify it?

Comment: I do not have your environment infront of me. but I would start by changing the permissions of the `/Debug/Cygwin-Windows` directory to allow both read and write to that directory

Comment: I don't know how to do that I'm new to this

Comment: one way to handle the changing of the permissions:  open a terminal window in cygwin then `cd /Debug` then `chmod 666 Cygwin-Windows`   Where the `666` will enable read+write permissions for current user, current group, and the world,   If you do a `ls -al` before calling `chmod` and again after calling `chmod` you will see the permission bits and how they have changed.  One thing to remember.  When running `cygwin` your effectively on a linux OS, even though the base OS of your computer is windows.

Comment: You can run the `setup` utility for cygwin and install all the `man` pages, then you can type into a cygwin terminal window: `man 1 chmod` to access a page that will tell you everything you might ever want to know about the `chmod` utility.  Infact, ALL the shell commands (like chmod) + C statements + masses of other information can be accessed.  Note there are 7 areas under the `man` command, of which the `chmod` is a shell command and all the shell commands are in area 1.  Remember, in linux/unix that capitalization counts, just like it does in C

Comment: I tried doing so but in cygwin terminal when I'm typing cd /Debug command it says no such file or directory
 Sharing terminal window pic with u:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQmn.png

Comment: Did you notice that the directory in question is relative to the current directory, not to the root directory AND the relative path is: `build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows`  I.E. take the working directory, cd build  cd Debug   So the first order of business is to find the `build` directory, which should be under the directory where you are compiling the code

Comment: Thank you for helping
I finally solved my problem by re-installing netbeans 
My C program is running although but at the end it is showing RUN FAILED although I am getting the output
I am unable to understand why is this happening

Comment: the reason for the `RUN FAILED` message is because the return type from `main()` is `void` rather than  the proper `int`   Your compiler should have told you that.  If it didn't tell you that, then enable all the warnings when compiling.